# 403 forbidden when downloading mongoDB driver for golang

Tags: mongodb, go, visual-studio-code, http-status-code-403

I'm trying to download mongoDB golang driver to a project in VS code running this command in the VS code terminal:

```
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
```

but I'm getting 403 forbidden error like this:

```
go: downloading github.com/klauspost/compress v1.13.6
go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo imports
       github.com/klauspost/compress/zstd: github.com/klauspost/compress@v1.13.6: reading https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/klauspost/compress/@v/v1.13.6.zip: 403 Forbidden
```

I've figured maybe my ip address is restriced so I've tried downloading it using several VPNs like psiphon and hotspot shield but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily skip using GOPROXY by:

```
GORPOXY='direct' go get YOUR_URL
```

This way, it skips the goproxy checking and directly downloads your repo from provided destination.

Comment: I'm getting this error when trying to run this command in VS code terminal: `The term 'GORPOXY=direct' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path     
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.` should I download something so I can use GOPROXY?

Comment: GOPROXY=direct is an environment. It is not a command. Where are you running your command? In any place, you need to test it via setting this env.

Comment: I'm new to golang can you tell me how to run the go get command with the value of GOPROXY equal to direct